# bash function to quickly push git commits not working

Tags: bash, git

I have the following function in my bash_profile that used to work for years and no longer works:

```
cmpushall() { git add -A; git commit "$1"; git push ;}
```

I now get the following error:

```
$ cmpushall "first promise"
error: pathspec 'first promise' did not match any file(s) known to git
Everything up-to-date
```

I havent written bash in years so I'm stumped, I always thought the $1 symbol would take an argument of the first string given to the command. The `git add -A` appears to have run, I have a file staged...the function errors out when trying to commit

any help appreciated

Comment: Do you mean `git commit -m "$1"`? (It's not a problem of your function `cmpushall` but Git's interpretation of your command line argument. See the documentation of `git commit`.) BTW: If you always use a combination of `git commit` and `git push` you will lose a lot of Git's flexibility.

Comment: thank you I didn't even notice that. I have no idea how this function used to work

Comment: What problems could arise by using git push each time? are there times where u want to save commits on local but not push?

Comment: There are several possibilities: A developer can commit untested changes locally in small steps and push everything when it is tested. Or a developer can commit locally often in small steps and combine commits to bigger ones later before pushing to the server. ... It depends on the way how you use Git if this will result in *problems* or only in loss of flexibility.

Comment: that makes sense, I haven;t smashed multiple commits into 1 in years so I forgot you can do that

Comment: @codyc4321: You can --amend previous commits instead of "whoops, forgot to add this file". You can throw away commits when it turns out that you've been working on a dead-end change. You can move commits to a branch when it turns out to be bigger than expected. (Editing already-pushed commits is possible but highly not-recommended when you have other people pulling from that repository; it tends to create a mess.) Not to mention being able to use `git add -p` to _partially_ commit a file, allowing several small and *easy-to-review* commits instead of large "rewrote everything".